Please flag posts which go against the site rules
The past few days a whole lot of flags were raised, but a few of them I had to decline since a simple down vote or comment was sufficient. Please only flag when needed! On the other hand, on one answer a considerable comment thread emerged regarding the answer being prescriptive, which we already decided on is problematic for many reasons. This answer could have been edited/flagged from the start. Please do so earlier on when possible. I feel these types of answers can be regarded in the same category as 'spam'. We simply don't allow them on this site.
Although I have no time for it now, I suggest we create a "When to flag?" faq specific to our site here on meta.
A short quick outline:

Flag when community moderation no longer suffices. E.g. flag questions which should be closed as per the site guidelines, but start receiving answers/up votes.
Flag when something is posted against the site guidelines (e.g. prescriptive answers).
Flag spam.
Flag offensive/rude behavior which is not conducive to the discussion.
Flag obsolete comments.

In other case just down vote, comment or edit in order to (partially) resolve the issue.
